# How close to a PVC stormwater drain can I get with a retaining wall post?

Tags: wall

I'm building a retaining wall along the length of my shed. I was hoping to run it 250mm offset from the shed. However, I've discovered a stormwater pipe running parallel for some of the proposed wall, also running 250mm off from the shed.

How close can I get my posts to this pipe? if I bring the wall closer to the shed, it would have to be 25mm off from the pipe.

If I build it on the far side of the pipe, I would have to excavate more dirt out... and its hot and would rather not :)

[image: Looking down the length of the proposed wall]

[image: Looking straight down]

[image: Another view]